# Kali linux 1.0.9 Wlan0 not found

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, kali-linux

I am running Linux **Kali 1.0.9-amd64** on the **Dell core i3** Inspiron.When I type '**ifconfig**' on Kali I don't get any information on **wlan0**.

Comment: Could you post the output of ifconfig?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think

1. You may not have sufficient privileges
2. Run `ip n show`
3. Run `ifconfig` again.

Do you get exactly **no** output? If you do get output, but not on wlan0, you may have an old wireless card that isn't wlan0. It might show something like this:

`lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>`

That's the info that you want, just you're wireless card interface has a different name.

Comment: Always happy to help....if not slightly late.

Answer (score 0):

You have to ***iwconfig*** instead of ***ifconfig***

```
root@kali:~# iwconfig


wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

---

```
root@kali:~# **lspci | grep -i wireless**


04:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
```

Note that in my case im on a desktop with a PCI card 
so if you plug a USB wireless stick change the

**lspci** to **lsusb**

```
root@kali:~# lsusb | grep -i wireless


Bus 002 Device 004: ID 148f:2070 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2070 Wireless Adapter
```

if you still have no output at all  you have to dig about your laptop or open the wirless card slot and note the exact name of your card and do some search on compta wirless and the aircrack-ng forum or other forums related to debian and your card without forget about injection

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a mother board needs some special driver that you can find in the repo under dkms. Install your required dkms and it will be fixed automatically.